# grep: etc/resolv.conf: The archive or directory does not exist

Tags: networking

I have problems when connecting to the internet because I can't connect to my router. So, I used the recovery mode to see if I can connect to the the network, but the process stopped and appeared this message:

```
grep: etc/resolv.conf: The archive or directory does not exist
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Sorry for my english but it isn't my first language, I tried to do my best!

Comment: The file is actually located at /etc/resolv.conf... but **DON'T** manually edit this file. Edit your question to include the output (in terminal) of `sudo lshw -C net` and `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

You will find the file at `/etc/resolv.conf`. The initial `/` is important, and specifies the root of the Linux/Unix file system. `etc/resolv.conf` looks for a directory called `etc` in your current directory, and looks for `resolv.conf` there (where it's not).